# Add curly braces to string after a match (sed)

Tags: regex, bash, command-line, sed

I'm a beginner with regexes and I'm trying to achieve something relatively simple:

I have a dataset arranged like this:

```
1,AAA,aaaa,BBB,bbbbbb ...
2,AAA,aaaaaaa,BBB,bbb ...
3,AAA,aaaaa,BBB,bb ...
```

I'm looking into adding curly brackets to the strings of various length (alphanumeric chars) following AAA or BBB (these are constant):

```
1,AAA,{aaaa},BBB,{bbbbbb} ...
2,AAA,{aaaaaaa},BBB,{bbb} ...
3,AAA,{aaaaa},BBB,{bb} ...
```

So I have tried with sed this way:

```
sed 's/(AAA|BBB)[[:punct:]].[[:alnum:]]/\1{&}/g' dataset.txt
```

However I got this result:

```
1,AAA,{AAA,aa}aa,BBB,{BBB,bb}bbbb, ... 
2,AAA,{AAA,aa}aaaaa,BBB,[BBB,bb}b, ...
3,AAA,{AAA,aa}aaa,BBB,{BBB,bb} ...
```

Obvisouly, the `&` in the replace part of `sed` is going to be the matched pattern, however, I would like `&` to be only what is after the matched patter, what am I doing wrong?

I have also tried adding word boundaries, after `[^ ]` to no avail. Am I trying too hard with `sed`? Should I use a language that allows lookbehind instead?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed 's/\(AAA\|BBB\),\([^,]*\)/\1,{\2}/g' dataset.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! That works like a charm! Why do I need to escape the parentheses?

Comment: @above comment: Or you could use `-r` option in sed.

Answer (score 1):

You can always have more than 1 capture groups in your regex, to capture different parts. You can even move the `[:punct:]` part inside the first capture group:

```
sed 's/((?:AAA|BBB)[[:punct:]])([[:alnum:]]+)/\1{\3}/g' dataset.txt
```

I don't understand what that `.` in between `[:punct:]` and `[:alnum:]` was doing. So, I removed it. Because of that, you might have noticed that, the regex was matching the following pattern:

```
{AAA,aa}
{BBB,bb}
```

i.e, it was matching just 2 characters after `AAA` and `BBB`. One for `.` and one for `[[:alnum:]]`.

To match all the alphanumeric characters after `,` till the next `,` you need to use quantifier: `[[:alnum:]]+`

Comment: thanks! I was confused about the use of parenthesis in regex but now it's quite clear! Basically, you need to tell `sed` to only wrap the third captured parenthesis (matched regex) in the `{}`. I had to pass `-er` flags to `sed` else it would give an error but this command doesn't seem to make any modification somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Following sed should work.

**On Linux:**

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/((AAA|BBB)[[:punct:]])([[:alnum:]]+)/\1{\3}/g'
```

**OR on OSX:**

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/((AAA|BBB)[[:punct:]])([[:alnum:]]+)/\1{\3}/g'
```

`-i` is for inline option to save changes in the input file itself.

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. Funnily enough this is the same solution as Rohit to the exception of the `:?` but I can't make his version work.

Comment: Does `sed -i.bak -r 's/(AAA|BBB),([[:alnum:]]+)/\1{\2}/g'` work for you?

Comment: this command doesn't keep the `,` after AAA or BBB which is needed downstream.

Comment: Ok in that case `sed -i.bak -r 's/(AAA|BBB),([[:alnum:]]+)/\1,{\2}/g'` should work for you.